# Where is the list of users returned from bash completion sourced from?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

For example, typing `compgen -u` on an Ubuntu box returns a list of users. This includes more users than are listed in `/etc/passwd` . So the question is when using bash completion to list out users, where does the list come from?

Comment: It seems to come from `/etc/passwd` on my machine here.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Presumably your machine isn't using NIS or LDAP; see my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed. I almost indicated that additional sources (such as NIS and LDAP) exist and how they might be found via `nsswitch.conf`/etc. but decided that the generic "go find out" answer was better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `strace -o compgen.out bash -c 'compgen -u'` and then look at the `compgen.out` file to try to find out what it is using.

On my machine that file ends with an `open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)` followed by the writing of the output.

Comment: This is the method I ended up using and was able to identify configuration files used and the unix socket that was queried to retrieve the user list.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/passwd` is the default source of user account information on UNIX-like systems, but it's often supplemented by other sources, paricularly on machines that are part of some larger organization that needs to keep that information consistent.

[NIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service) (formerly known as "YP") is one common system. [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldap) is another. I'm sure there are others.

The `getent passwd` command should show you all the relevant account information. On my machine (which doesn't use NIS or LDAP), it's equivalent to `cat /etc/passwd`; on yours, it will probably show additional information.

The various `getpw*()` functions (`getpwuid()`, `getpwnam()`, `getpwent()`) retrieve user account information, equivalent to what's in `/etc/passwd` plus whatever supplement your system uses. Presumably both the `getent` command and `bash` use this mechanism to obtain the relevant information.